# How can I implement an invitation system using Flutter and Firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing a Flutter app that is using the firebase realtime database. The app shall be used collaboratively by users to collect and analyze data. Users are part of a team and the data that is collected will be associated with the team. For a user to join a team, they are required to use an invitation link that is sent out by the team leader. The invite shall use the teamId which is a unique identifier for each team.

How could I go about this.

Comment: It is a broad question because I did not know where to start having spend many hours trying to find an answer.

Comment: This may be useful although using the FirebaseAdmin SDK https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hlxby1Mmic8&list=PLw5h0DiJ-9PDd2VvUZArXQpKIKdMB-Sga

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have a two-step process:

1. Create a link for a specific team that the user can click to then get into the app as part of the team.
2. Sending that link to the user.

For that type of link you can use Firebase Dynamic Links, for which a Flutter wrapper exists: [`firebase_dynamic_links` plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links).

For sending the link you have many options, but the most common ones are to send it through email or SMS/text message. When the user then clicks the link, it can open your app, and you can [extract information about the team from the link](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links#handle-received-dynamic-links).

If the target user is already using your app, you can of course skip all this and create a notification system through the Realtime Database. There's nothing pre-made for that, but it's just more use of the APIs you're already using.

Comment: Thanks, I am already using Firebase RTD so maybe your second idea is the way to go. Having said that, how would that type of notification be implemented?

Comment: After a little searching, I think I can use a Cloud Function to send a notification, with the team ID, to a user when the team leader adds them to the team. Thanks again for the pointer.